# Error while exporting inference graph in Object Detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, models, object-detection, attributeerror

I am a beginner in machine learning and currently trying to follow the tutorial by @sentdex for tracking Custom Objects.

I had completed training a model which gave me model.ckpt files. (https://pythonprogramming.net/training-custom-objects-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/)

Now for testing the model we need to export the inference graph. (https://pythonprogramming.net/testing-custom-object-detector-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/)

I run the following command from the models/research/object-detection folder  (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/) on the Command Prompt:

```
export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path training\ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training\model.ckpt-292  --output_directory mac_n_cheese_inference_graph
```

And obtain the following errors: ( *the cmd screen is attached*)

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

```
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\models\research\object_detection\export_inference_graph.py", line 149, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\models\research\object_detection\export_inference_graph.py", line 145, in main
    FLAGS.output_directory, input_shape)
  File "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/models/research/object_detection\exporter.py", line 452, in export_inference_graph
    is_training=False)
  File "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/models/research/object_detection/builders\model_builder.py", line 91, in build
    return _build_ssd_model(model_config.ssd, is_training, add_summaries)
  File "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/models/research/object_detection/builders\model_builder.py", line 152, in _build_ssd_model
    is_training)
  File "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/models/research/object_detection/builders\model_builder.py", line 118, in _build_ssd_feature_extractor
    use_explicit_padding = feature_extractor_config._use_explicit_padding
AttributeError: 'SsdFeatureExtractor' object has no attribute '_use_explicit_padding'
```

Please help correct the issue

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Also, if you're looking for debugging help, you'll need to be more specific: see "questions seeking debugging help" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @DanHall Sorry. I've elaborated my issue